# Extending component class exported wrapped in a HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

This question had something to do with `react-admin` until I realized the problem was the was the component I was extending was actually exported.

I'm using a react-admin's `TabbedForm` and child `FormTab` to show lots of fields in my admin, and I need to customize a tab's layout.

Basically I want to extend `FormTab` with a custom layout.

But I'm not getting anywhere.

Here is the problem :

If I use a custom component for my tabs like

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    FormTab,
    FormInput,
} from 'react-admin'

const hiddenStyle = { display: 'none' };
export class CustomFormTab extends FormTab {
    renderContent = ({ children, hidden, ...inputProps }) => (
        <span style={hidden ? hiddenStyle : null}>
            {React.Children.map(
                children,
                child => React.cloneElement(child, {
                        ...inputProps
                    })
            )}
        </span>
    );
}

export const CustomFormTabPart = ({ children, className, ...inputProps }) => {
    return (
    <div className={className}>
        {React.Children.map(
            children,
            input =>
                input && (
                    <FormInput
                        {...inputProps}
                        input={input}
                    />
                )
        )}
    </div>
    )
}
```

This should get me going but I'm extending `FormTab` which not exported as a simple component.

```
// in react-admin/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/FormTab.js
...
FormTab.displayName = 'FormTab';

export default translate(FormTab);
```

`translate` is a HOC...

I don't know how to extend this. Is that even possible ?

Actually the code in `FormTab` is not huge and copy-pasting it is a solution. I just hate like it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to export original class as named export along with default export but this wasn't done in [`FormTab` module](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v2.7.1/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/form/FormTab.js#L14).

It's a good practice to expose wrapped component (as can be seen in React Router's `withRouter`, React Redux's `connect` and so on) as static property on decorated component but this wasn't done in [`translate` HOC](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v2.7.1/packages/ra-core/src/i18n/translate.tsx#L46-L48).

Since `translate` wraps original `FormTab` component with context component, a quick-and-dirty fix is to deconstruct a hierarchy of React components:

```
const translateContext = FormTab.prototype.render();
const callback = translateContext.props.children;
const OriginalFormTab = callback({ translate: () => {}, label: '' }).type;

@translate
export class CustomFormTab extends OriginalFormTab { ... }
```

Since this is a hack that relies on third-party library internals, it may become broken with new library release, so it cannot be recommended, or at least requires to write unit test that tests internals in use.

A more appropriate solution is to fork a library, fix the drawbacks that were described (expose wrapped component in `translate` or/and export original components from modules) and submit a PR.